# Compare 2 int arrays for matching numbers - java

Tags: java

Hi may someone suggest the fastest way to compare 2 arrays in java
returning a string of an intersection array 
or a 'nil' value if there are no matches

```
static int [] WinnerNumbers; static int [] ClientNumbers;
```

After executing my program, I end up with 2 filled arrays (WinnerNumbers and ClientNumbers) of which I need to compare and return a match or null.

I would like to do this via a function

```
public static String WinnerChecker(){

      prize = (......)

      return prize;
}
```

Comment: Does a match have to be in a matching position?  For example, if the inputs are `{ 1, 2, 3, 4}` and `{5, 6, 1, 4}`, should the output be `{1,4}` or just `{4}`?

Comment: Hi GBlodgett, the outputs should be {1,4}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it like this.  It returns an empty String if no intersection (which is what I presumed you meant by `nil`).

```
        int[] a = { 1, 2, 4, 3 ,5, 9};
        int[] b = { 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13 };

        String intersection = getIntersection(a, b);
        System.out.println(intersection);

        public static String getIntersection(int[] a, int[] b) {
            return Arrays.stream(a)
                .flatMap(i -> Arrays.stream(b).filter(k -> i == k))
                .mapToObj(String::valueOf)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(""));
        }
```

Prints

```
459
```

If there are duplicates in either array and they are not wanted in the output, then add the method `.distinct()` right before the `mapToObj` process.

If one wants to return the result as an array, the following works.

```
    public static int[] getIntersection(int[] a, int[] b) {
        return Arrays.stream(a)
                .flatMap(i -> Arrays.stream(b).filter(k -> i == k))
                .toArray();

    }
```

Another way which may be more efficient than those above is using sets.

```
    public static String getIntersection(int[] a, int[] b) {
        Set<Integer> seta =
                Arrays.stream(a).boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet());
        Set<Integer> setb =
                Arrays.stream(b).boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet());

        seta.retainAll(setb);
        return seta.stream().map(String::valueOf)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(""));
    }
```

The actual set could be returned instead if that is desired.

Comment: WJS this method worked like a charm, i've spent a lot of time researching ways people have approached this scenario and your answer is by far the most clean coded and simple. Thanks a bunch

Comment: Yeh i noticed this, I had '6' twice in my winners. But this is beneficial for me as my project didn't specify a unique number in each element of Client Choice. If the b and a were switched, repeats may be a problem, but in context, the repeats plays in my favour

Comment: I am posting an update to my answer to elimiinate this if desired.  It is easy to do.

Comment: Is there a way you can post a 'second answer' (your first answer)  - just incase somebody else would like to return the array. - from googling this, resources are terrible so I think the original would also be very helpful to people who would want to just return the array instead of a string like myself

Answer (score 0):

Create a set with the winner array. For each number of the client check if the number exists in the set.

- Set contains is O(1)
- Iterate over client array O(N)

Overall complexity will be O(N)

```
private static String findWinners(int[] winnerNumbers, int[] clientNumbers) {
    Set<Integer> winnerNumberSet = IntStream.of(winnerNumbers).boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet());

    Optional<String> output = IntStream.of(clientNumbers)
            .filter(winnerNumberSet::contains)
            .mapToObj(String::valueOf)
            .reduce((result, element) ->
                    result + ", " + element);

    return output.orElse(null);
}
```

Comment: Hi Shakhawat, Thank you for the answer, I will try it out as an alternative way of implementing my function. I really like your return function and will use it in the future. Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Hope below code useful for you.

```
 String prize="";
    int[] winnerNumbers={ 23,84,32,98,11};
    int[] clientNumbers ={ 82, 70,81,98,41,32};
    for(int i=0; i< winnerNumbers.length; i++){
        for(int j=0; j< clientNumbers.length; j++){

            if(winnerNumbers[i] == clientNumbers[j]){
                prize = prize + winnerNumbers[i] +" ";
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(prize);
```

Here linear search operation perform to locate number. You can Java 8 stream class or other searching algorithm as per you array size. For more searching algorithm refer below link.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-if-a-value-is-present-in-an-array-in-java/

Comment: Hi Chaitanya, thanks for the help. I will give it a try as something alternative. Have a try with the code below from WJS, it's a newer approach without many loops and iterations. Thank you again :)